Is every acyclic graph with $n$ vertices and $n -1$ edges a tree?
A tree is acyclic by definition, and according to a well known theorem, it has $n-1$ edges, where $n$ is the number of vertices.
Now I'm asking myself if every acyclic graph with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges is a tree and how that could be proven if it's true.
I want it to be true since that would give me a way to count the number of spanning trees of a graphs by a nice combinatorial argument in the form of inclusion-exclusion. The Kirchhoff determinant method seems dull and cumbersome to me, and I would like to avoid using that if possible.

To check, are you referring to directed graphs, or undirected graphs?

Undirected graphs.

Every undirected acyclic graph (aka a graph with no cycles) is by definition a tree. It is independent of how many edges it has.

Doesn’t it have to be connected also?

@CalvinLin A tree is usually defined to be a connected acyclic graph. If we remove the connected assumption, it is usually called a forest.

Yes, that's what I thought.

It is true. We just need to show the graph (call it $G$) is connected. Let $G_1,...,G_k$ be its connected components, each one of them is a tree. Then:
$n-1=|E(G)|=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k |E(G_i)|=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (|V(G_i)|-1)=|V(G)|-k=n-k.$
And so $k=1$, i.e $G$ is connected.

Nice! Is your argument approximately this: Every acyclic graph is a forest, and for each tree in a forest we get a lowering of the number of edges compared to the number of vertices by one. So if the difference between those numbers in an acyclic graph as a whole is just one, then it has to consist of only one tree?

@AA Yes, that's the idea of the proof.

I'm glad I got the idea right.
